# How to Set HttpPost Headers for a Client Request in Java Android

Tags: java, android, oauth, http-headers, http-post

I am having trouble getting the Apache HttpClient to correctly send an HttpPost Header.

I have no problems sending name value pairs and whatnot, but whenever I set or add a POST Header, it disappears when the request is made.

I have tried both setHeader and addHeader, as well as trying both at once.

Here is my code:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://posttestserver.com/post.php");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization: Bearer", accessToken);
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization: Bearer", accessToken);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "HEADERS: " + httppost.getFirstHeader("Authorization: Bearer"));

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

    Log.d("DEBUG", "RESPONSE: " + responseBody);
```

Additionally, the debug statement before the request is executed prints out the correct header, so I know it is being added, then just dropped later.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** This is all running inside of an AsyncTask if that matters.  I don't think it does since there is a NetworkOnMainThread exception thrown otherwise but I thought it might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to connect the service that [tells your HTTP headers](http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php) and capture (just print plain HTML) the output. At least you will know if your headers are really lost on the way or maybe something else.

Comment: The header I sent did not show up in the response, in fact from the response it looks like no headers whatsoever were sent.

Comment: Gemein. Probably not a solution then but at least we have narrowed the possible area where the bug can be.

Answer (score 22):

At least one mistake in your code. Try this instead:

```
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the header still gets dropped :(

Comment: What do you mean by dropped? You see a request with no headers on the server side?

Comment: Yeah, the Authorization header is nonexistant

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty simple request so I have no idea what could be wrong with it, I've had other people take a look too and they don't know either...Thanks though

Comment: This is all running inside of an AsyncTask if that matters.  I don't think it does since there is a NetworkOnMainThread exception thrown otherwise but I thought it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Your server is hiding that particular header. Try something else like: httppost.setHeader("-Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

Answer (score 1):

You said the header is not on the response in one of your replies, just to clarify, headers don't come back on the response, they are just sent on the request to the server. A network trace or fiddler session can show the request and response, and this should give you a definitive answer of whether they are getting dropped or not.

Answer (score 0):

try using `java.net.URLConnection.addRequestProperty(String field, String newValue)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I have tried this by following various tutorials like this one: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Headers are still not appearing.

Answer (score -1):

Personally i prefer use an other methos to set properly the http authorization:

```
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
  new AuthScope(hostname, port), 
  new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass));
```

Comment: My code is part of an OAuth token request, so I don't think this will work unfortunately...