# Getting Google Play Games player ID on server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-games

The post [Play Games Permissions are changing in 2016](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) explains how to get the Play Games player ID on a server.  I can successfully get the access token on the server, but I can't get this step to work:

> 7. Once you have the access token, call www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/yourAppId/verify/ using that
>      access token. Pass the auth token in a header as follows:
>      “Authorization: OAuth ” The response value will contain
>      the player ID for the user.

I'm trying to do that in Google App Engine using:

```
accessToken = ...;   //-- I can always get this successfully
URL url = new URL(String.format("https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/%s/verify/",myAppId));    
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET);
HTTPHeader httpHeader = new HTTPHeader("Authorization: OAuth",accessToken);
request.addHeader(httpHeader);
HTTPResponse httpResponse = urlFetchService.fetch(request);
```

The response always return code 401.  How can I debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the header, it should be added like this:

```
HTTPHeader httpHeader = new HTTPHeader("Authorization","OAuth " + accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

An [identical issue (sort of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655062/how-to-set-httppost-headers-for-a-client-request-in-java-android) indicates that you'll have to set the header differently (not using `HttpHeader`).

httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

Hopefully this can fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @adjuremods, you are partially correct in that I was including the ":" in my header, and the "OAuth " should be part of the header value, not the header name.